# How to use SQL CREATE TABLE with PostgreSQL and MySQL if I have user column?

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql

I want write SQL file use by `PostgreSQL` **AND** `MySQL` but the `user` column need `"user"` with `PostgreSQL` and need `user` with `MySQL`

**PostgreSQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE mail_user (
   "user" char(50) NOT NULL,
   domain char(50) NOT NULL,
   password char(50) NOT NULL
);
```

**MySQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE mail_user (
   user char(50) NOT NULL,
   domain char(50) NOT NULL,
   password char(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: I would keep it simple, and I would change user to user_name, user_id or whatever similar. Unless you have some internal reason why it MUST be a user.

Comment: You are correct, Postgres and MySql cannot handle this the same. However there is not need for the column name `user`, it can be `user_id` or `userid` or  other version. Both DBMS can then handle the same column name.

Comment: You can use ANSI_QUOTES for MySQL (https://mariadb.com/docs/skysql-dbaas/ref/xpand/sql-modes/ANSI_QUOTES/). But this is not the best advice...

Comment: Here's a table of ANSI SQL reserved words, together with Postgresql, MySQL and others: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words

Comment: Piling on to what others are saying. Another reason to avoid this keyword is that it's not just a nuisance when creating the table. It's a nuisance every single time this table is queried. In perpetuity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When designing tables, it's generally a good practice to avoid using reserved words for database, column, and table names. This is especially true when creating data definition language (DDL) statements intended to be portable between makes and versions of server. That's because the rules for where reserved words are allowed vary from server to server, and because the way you delimit them also varies. In postgreSQL, you write `"user"`. In SQL Server you write `[user]`, and in MySQL you write

```
`user`
```

Just avoid the reserved words and you avoid all that mischegoss.

`user` is a reserved word. If this were my project I would call the column `username`.